# Unknown/generic error in Jenkins when running command from within a Docker Image

Tags: docker, jenkins, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to execute the following command from a Jenkins file that is running inside a Docker image: `sh "cd ./src/common && npm install"`

Jenkins Log shows the following:

```
18:56:46  + cd ./src/common
18:56:46  + npm install
18:56:46  
[Pipeline] }
18:56:46  $ docker stop --time=1 
    02b60e1ac63b72e7a57356249d7ba48b720bf6f0c7df2addd20b7a2d45201ef5
18:56:48  $ docker rm -f 
    02b60e1ac63b72e7a57356249d7ba48b720bf6f0c7df2addd20b7a2d45201ef5
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] echo
18:56:48  Exception: hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 243
[Pipeline] error
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timestamps
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 243
```

When I run this without using a docker image, it runs fine. However, I need to now use a Docker image.

The following is my Docker image file:

```
FROM node:16 

ENV PROJECT_DIR /usr/local/bin/src/oppt
WORKDIR ${PROJECT_DIR}

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install zip -y 
RUN apt-get install curl -y 

RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
RUN unzip awscliv2.zip
RUN ./aws/install

COPY . ${PROJECT_DIR}/
```

I have tried this: `sh(script: """ #!/bin/bash pushd ./src/common && npm install && popd""")`

But it still did not work.

The error is in `npm install` somehow, but it's not throwing it or being logged in jenkins.

I've done a `ls` of the `./src/common` directory and the expected files are there, `package.json` and `package-lock.json`

`npm install` should create a `node-modules` folder and put the dependencies in it and this is not happening. If it's an IO rights issue then it ought to throw such error, but it's not. Or even if the package files were bad (which they arent') it should throw some kind of error saying so.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Aren't you expecting to find `package.json` and `package-lock.json`, rather than `package` and `package-lock`? What exactly do you see from `ls -la` in the `src/common` directory?

Comment: Seems exit code 243 is returned for permission issue. Does this help to solve your issue?  https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Comment: Thanks. I tried both, reinstalling NPM in Docker has the same effect. When I tried reconfiguring to use a global, I get the following error: `21:36:54  Step 7/14 : RUN source ~/.profile
21:36:54   ---> Running in 07d739c6f244
21:36:55  [91m/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
21:36:55  [0mThe command '/bin/sh -c source ~/.profile' returned a non-zero code: 127`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this:

```
sh "HOME=${WORKSPACE} && cd ${WORKSPACE}/src/common && some command"
```

Have to set the Docker workspace location first, then go to the location and do the command you want.